# JAXB - marshall generic type (Date)

Tags: java, generics, jaxb

I am having trouble to marshall/unmarshall generic type using JAXB.
Everything works fine, but when my generic field is Date (java.util.Date), unmarshalling will produce XMLGregorianCalendar instead

here is a piece of code I am talking about:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Entity<T> {
    private T field;

    public Entity() {
    }

    public T getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(T field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
}
```

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class JaxbTest {
    public JaxbTest() {

        Entity<Date> ent = new Entity<Date>();
        ent.setField(new Date());

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        try {
            // marshall
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Entity.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(ent, sw);

            // unmarshall
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Entity.class);
            Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            Entity<Date> ent2 = (Entity<Date>) u.unmarshal(new StringReader(sw
                    .toString()));// exception is thrown here
            System.out.println(ent2.getField());
        } catch (JAXBException e11) {
            e11.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JaxbTest();
    }

}
```

the above code throws exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl cannot be cast to java.util.Date
    at JaxbTest.<init>(JaxbTest.java:31)
    at JaxbTest.main(JaxbTest.java:38)
```

Could you help me how to fix it? I was thinking about some adapter that would be "active" only if field is Date, but I don't think it is possible

thanks

Comment: I'm guessing you made a mistake, and that the error is on the line with `ent2.getField()`?

Answer (score 1):

A `JAXBContext` is built on classes and not types.  As far your JAXB (JSR-222) implementation is aware, the `field` property is of type `Object`.  If you add the following to your code:

```
        String xml = sw.toString();
        System.out.println(xml);
```

You will see the output XML is the following.  An `xsi:type` attribute has been added to preserve that the text value contains date information.  On the `unmarshal` operation since JAXB thinks the property is of type `Object` it will recognize the `xsi:type` attribute and convert the value to the default date type which is `XMLGregorianCalendar`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<entity>
    <field xsi:type="xs:dateTime" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">2012-10-29T15:20:17.763-04:00</field>
</entity>
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how i could teach JAXB to use java.util.Date or any other Date implementation?

Comment: Firstly an adapter(which extends XMLAdapter) can be used for it. A second approach, after message received, use xmlGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar().getTime() method for convert it to date object.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a generic field in an abstract class. I solved it by adding an annotated getter/setter which parses the value to/from a string. The getter/setter is then overwritten in my subclasses.

This was my solution:

```
@XmlSeeAlso({DateEntity.class})
@XmlType
public abstract class Entity<T> {
    private T field;

    public Entity() {}

    public T getField() {
        return this.field;
    }

    public void setField(T field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="value", required = true)
    public abstract String getSerializeField();
    public abstract void setSerializeField(String value);
}
```

My date sublcass:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name="dateEntity")
public class DateEntity extends Entity<Date> {

    public DateEntity() {}

    @Override
    public String getSerializeField(){
        DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getInstance();
        return formatter.format(field);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSerializeField(String value) {
        DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getInstance();
        this.value = formatter.parse(value);
    }
}
```

Hope this is helpful...